# Can VAR still intervene for a penalty call review even if the possession has changed many times?

Tags: rules, football, officiating, video-review

Here's a scenario. The home team player has been fouled inside his/her opponents’ penalty area and the referee says play on.  Then:

- Home team loses the ball and away team starts a counter attack.
- Away team loses the ball and home team regains possession.
- This cycle goes on once more.

If the play did not stop during this period, can VAR still intervene for a penalty call review?

Answer (score 0):

The hypothetical situation in question will never occur.

Presuming a review is permitted (the incident is reviewable, and is a *clear and obvious error*), if the video assistant referee was going to intervene, it would have been at the time possession moved into a neutral area - as soon as the Away team obtained possession and before they "start a counter attack".

VAR Protocol, section 4 *Procedures*, subsection *Review*,

> If play has not already stopped, the referee stops play when the ball is next in a neutral zone/situation (usually when neither team is in an attacking move) and shows the 'TV signal'